# calling function inside for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Okay so here is my loop:

```
if (list.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            let fruit = list[i].attributes;
            if (fruit.color === 'red') {
                id = fruit.id;
                fruit.path = base.fruit_directory + "/" + id;
                saveFruit(id);
            }
        }
}
```

Now, whenever a fruit that is  === red comes along. Save fruit isnt automatically executed.But after all other things go off, Why is this?

Any workarounds?

Comment: is `saveFruit` a sync function?

Comment: you are using let i and using j  for checking length and incrementing j ,

Comment: Is the `saveFruit` method asynchronous? If yes, then that is why. If you want it to complete before iterating over the next "fruit", you can either have it return a promise, or make it synchronous. Also, your loop initialization is using `j` instead of `i`. You never initialized variable `j`. Also, your loop is iterating over `i`, but `i` is never being incremented. So, you are only ever checking the 1st element of your fruits array

Comment: Your code is both incomplete and invalid. Post a real demo.

Comment: @EvanBechtol How do i make it synchronous?

Comment: @joe123 You would have to update your post with the existing code for myself, or anyone else to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming saveFruit returns a promise (if it doesn't please post that function):

```
Promise.all(
  list.map(item=>item.attributes)//map list items to fruit
  .filter(fruit=>fruit.color==="red")//only red fruit
  .map(f=>saveFruit(base.fruit_directory +"/"+f.id))//map fruit to promise resolving in response
).then(
  responses=>console.log("got responses:",responses)
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `fruit.path` be `f.path`?

Comment: @EvanBechtol no, it should be `base.fruit_directory` I changed that